# How to write a Django view for a POST request

Tags: python, django, post

I have written a very small example: a junit button which sends a POST request with a pair of values:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        var postdata = {
            'value1': 7,
            'value2': 5
        };
        $.post('', postdata); // POST request to the same view I am now
        window.alert("Hello world!"); // To know it is working
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Submit</button>


</body>
</html>
```

So, the view is rendered when a GET request is sent to localhost:8000/button/, and when the button is pushed a POST request is also sent to localhost:8000/button/.

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^button/$', 'helloworld.views.buttonExample'),
    )
```

## views.py

```
def buttonExample(request):
    print 'RECEIVED REQUEST: ' + request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'Hello'
    else: #GET
        return render(request, 'buttonExample.html')
```

When the GET request is done, the view is displayed correctly and I can also read at Django console the lines:

```
RECEIVED REQUEST: GET <---- This line is because of my print
[28/May/2013 05:20:30] "GET /button/ HTTP/1.1" 200 140898
[28/May/2013 05:20:30] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[28/May/2013 05:20:30] "GET /static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[28/May/2013 05:20:30] "GET /static/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
...
```

And when the button is pushed, I can see:

```
[28/May/2013 05:20:34] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 403 142238
```

But "RECEIVED REQUEST: POST" is never printed. Neither is "Hello". It seems like the urls.py is not serving the view when a POST arrived, because in Firebug I can see that POST status is 403 FORBIDDEN.

This is probably a silly newbie mistake, but I don't know what am I missing. I have read the [django book chapter about advanced URLConf and Views](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html), and it looks like it should work just by checking request.method value.

Comment: ADD csrf token to ur template..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is by design. Your POST data must contain `csrfmiddlewaretoken` value. You can get it from your cookies and then send it with POST requests. [Details here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/) For your specific case, you can do this -

```
<script>
$(function () {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $("button")
        .button()
        .click(function (event) {
            var postdata = {
                'value1': 7,
                'value2': 5,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
            };
            $.post('', postdata); // POST request to the same view I am now
            window.alert("Hello world!"); // To know it is working
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I just added the line 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' = $.cookie('csrftoken'),' to the postdara variable, and the POST is not being sent any more

Comment: BTW, using `$.cookie` requires jQuery cookie plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You are receiving a 403 because of CSRF protection - you have not provided a token to protect yourself from attacks. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/) tells you all you need to know.