# Why I am getting a GET request on the django side while sending a POST request with superagent

Tags: python, django, superagent

I am sending a POST request to the server application using [superagent.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/). The request is sent to a `django` view. But I am getting a GET request on the view side.

Here is my code where I am trying to send a request with `superagent`:

```
request.post('/nameofview')
.set('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.set('X-CSRFToken', csrf)
.send({name: 'name'})
.end(callback)
```

These are logs from the `django` development server:

```
[30/Mar/2016 12:27:28] "POST /nameofview HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[30/Mar/2016 12:27:28] "GET /ru/nameofview HTTP/1.1" 404(<--Raising not found from within the view) 1696
```

So, `django` project url dispatcher is receiving a post request but then redirecting it to the application view as a get request. **I don't have any problems with url matching. Execution enters view code, but it is a get request not a post and that's why I can't get the post data I have sent.**

This is my view code:

```
def nameofview(request):
    if 'name' in request.POST:
        # make some staff
        return JsonResponse({'result': result})
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789988/how-to-write-a-django-view-for-a-post-request), I figured out that I have to attach a csrftoken to my post request, and of course I did this as it is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) without any success.

So, my question is, why it is doing this and how can I make it not touch my post request?

*P.S. It works with get request without any problem.*

Comment: Please add your `view`-method behind `/url`. I assume, you have a redirect there from `/url` to `/ru/url` what the status code `302` indicates. Or is `ru` a language code and you are using any language package in django which adds the language to the url?

Comment: Post the code for the view that's handling the first request. It's redirecting you to the second URL.

Comment: I have made some corrections to my question. Yes, @omeinusch, `ru` is a language code, and redirection occurs in projects `urls.py`, here exactly `urlpatterns += 18n_patterns(   url(r'^', include('app.urls')))`.

Comment: show the view code which is handling the redirects

Comment: @sehrob How do you know that it is not a POST? You are only checking if there is a variable named `name` in the POST request. Try checking with `if request.method == 'POST':` first to make sure.

Comment: @Selcuk This can be deduced from the server log where it states that the first (`POST`) request is redirected and the second is a `GET` request

Comment: @TimSchneider You are right. It is probably the redirection then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounir seems to be on the right track. However the trailing `/` does not seem to be the problem. Instead, Django is adding a `/ru` to the front of the requested URL. Could `ru` possibly be the descriptor for a language that you encode in your url? If so, try to call `request.post('/ru/nameofview/')`.

On the other hand, superagent seems to call the redirects with a `GET` request instead of a `POST` so the `allow_redirects=True` function that Mounir proposed could also do the trick, though I am not familiar with that library.

Comment: `request.post('/ru/nameofview/')` did the trick! Thank you very much @Tim Schneider!  Thank you @omeinusch too!