# How to send an object back to Django view and access it by indexing

Tags: python, django

In my HTML I have an object `data` .Data was originally retrieved from a SQL query in Django in `views.py` and passed on to the HTML using render()

`data` looks like this

```
data1= {
        0:{
            pk:1,
            model:"binaryQuestionApp.painting",
            fields: {title:'Pearl',artist:"vermeer"},
        },
        1:{
            pk:2,
            model:"binaryQuestionApp.painting",
            fields: {title:'Sand',artist:"vermeer"},
        }
    }
```

I use the following JS so send `data` back to `views.py` (I create csrftoken using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789988/how-to-write-a-django-view-for-a-post-request))

```
function post_data() {
    var postdata = {
        'data': data,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
    };
    $.post('', postdata); // POST request to the same view I am now
};
```

Now, data is being send back to the server, but I'm having trouble accessing it. I have this in my `views.py`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST
    # so far it works. But i can not index like this:
    print(data[0]['pk']
    # instead I need to index it strangely, like this:
    print(data['data[0][pk]']) # note the entire key is a string
```

How can I send data to Django so that i can access it in `views.py` using data[0]['pk']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

First you need to parse the object to JSON.

```
var postdata = {
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
};
```

Then `postdata` can be send using (note $, this used jquery)

```
$.post('', postdata); // POST request to the same view I am now
```

On server side, in `views.py` you need to use the `get()` method:

```
import json 
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        data = json.loads(data)
        print(data[0]['model'])  # this indexing will depend on your own setup, works just like any python dict
```