# How to pass url value in django to views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My url.py is as below,

```
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^myapp/get_requests/$', views.get_requests),
]
```

Now my views.py is as below,

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_request(request):
   #How can I get request ID (base url here)?
   return HttpResponse('test')
```

In the above if I do request in my browser with url as below it reaches my get_request method,

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/get_requests/
```

But the same gives error 404 when I try with some ID in the end as below,

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/get_requests/40
```

Now How can I get this ID number 40 in my views.py method?

Comment: make a function with post request allowed where you give id as payload .....
go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789988/how-to-write-a-django-view-for-a-post-request for how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your urls.py to

```
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^myapp/get_requests/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.get_requests),
]
```

Now get the id parameter in your views like this

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_request(request,id):
    print id
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

For more information check out [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick up `id` from url, you just have to write something like this :

```
@login_required
def MyFunction(request, id) :

    myobject = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=id)

    context = {
            "myobject" : myobject,
    }

    return render(request, 'my template.html', context)
```

And your url, you have to add `url(r'^myapp/get_requests/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.get_requests),`

I assume your url is correct and he's already created with `id` inside. So I just gave you How I pick up object according to this ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the view function name in your above code. So, it would be `get_requests` not `get_request`.

Now coming to your question, it throws you `404 - Not Found` because there is no actual route that you've defined that should expect the id after the url.

To start accepting id, add another route for it in your `urls.py` which has a digit regext like:

```
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^myapp/get_requests/$', views.get_requests),
   url(r'^myapp/get_requests/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.get_requests_with_id),
]
```

and in your `views.py`, define the view function to accept `id` parameter something like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_requests_with_id(request, id):
   # Now use id for whatever you want
   return HttpResponse('test')
```

You can read about it form the official documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups